# grep -E with Radare2

Tags: radare2

With Radare2, I love the `iI` command.

I want to limit the output with grep or radare's own grep syntax.

How do I run a `iI | grep -E 'bits | pic | stripped'` against my binary?

```
[0x100001200]> iI
arch     x86
binsz    38688
bintype  mach0
bits     64
....
..
.
```

My intention is to run this command inside a python script using `r2pipe`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Radare's grep is done by using the `~` character.

```
 ~?<br>
|Usage: [command]~[modifier][word,word][endmodifier][[column]][:line]
```

So to have the output you want just run:

```
iI~bits,pic,stripped

[0x100001200]> iI~bits,pic,stripped
bits     64
pic      true
stripped true
```

The same command you should run in your script. There's a lot of more that this grep can do. To get the help of it just run the `~?`

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for. Next I will try and work out why the json flag + grep instruction doesn't work with: `iIj~bits,pic,stripped`. But I can do that solo. Thanks again.

Comment: json supports a limited grep in a form: `iIj~{bits}` but you would have to grep for the three things separately.

Comment: That actually gives me a better answer.  I can now use `iIj~{stripped}` as it return the value (true / false) instead of the Key Value Pair you get with `iI~stripped` (stripped true)